# How to get a tcolorbox with only frame

Tags: tcolorbox

I want to construct a ***pure*** framed box （which is like the typeset of `\fboxsep0pt\fbox{\parbox{\textwidth}{...}}` with `tcolorbox`. This box has not any layout, except the frame whose width is 2pt. I'd like to use it as a container.

I tried by the following code and failed. No frame is typeset. How to make `boxrule=2pt` work after `blankest`?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\begin{document}

\begin{tcolorbox}[blankest,boxrule=2pt]
  some text
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

Comment: with \begin{tcolorbox}[colback=white,boxrule=2pt]

Comment: Why not just ` \fbox` with `\fboxrule` to 2pt ?

Comment: @Fran because I'll put verbatim(listings for example) in it. `\fbox` can not do that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't need the framed box to be breakable, then `\fcolorbox` from `xcolor` is enough. Otherwise, a `tcolorbox` attempt based on the first example for skin `empty` in the package manual is provided.

Note the frame is drawn by `borderline` because in `tcolorbox` the border (whose width is controlled by option `boxrule`) is the difference of two filled rectangle, with possibly rounded corners, see the package manual, sec. 9.4 "Drawing Scheme".

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{skins}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\fboxsep0pt \fboxrule=2pt

1. \verb|\fbox| \\
\noindent\fbox{\parbox{\textwidth}{\lipsum[1][1-3]}}

2. \verb|\fcolorbox| from \verb|xcolor| \\
\noindent\fcolorbox{gray}{white}{\parbox{\textwidth}{\lipsum[1][1-3]}}

3. \verb|{tcolorbox}|, based on skin \verb|empty| \\
\tcbset{my empty box/.style={
  empty,
  borderline={2pt}{0pt}{black!10!white},
  left=0pt, right=0pt,
  top=0pt, bottom=0pt,
  boxsep=\fboxsep,
  sharp corners,
}}
\begin{tcolorbox}[my empty box]
  \lipsum[1][1-3]
\end{tcolorbox}

4. \verb|{tcolorbox}|, based on skin \verb|empty|, with width and before/after codes configured\\
\begin{tcolorbox}[my empty box, nobeforeafter, width=\linewidth+4pt]
  \lipsum[1][1-3]
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Many thanks especially for the description of `frame`!!